# How to overload the [] operator to support both assignment and const parameters in other functions?

Tags: c++, class, oop, operator-overloading, c++17

Consider a class `SomeClass`:

```
class SomeClass{
    public:
        // Constructors, other members
        float& operator[](const unsigned i);
        friend bool operator==(const SomeClass &A, const SomeClass &B);
};
```

Suppose this is how the `==` operator is overloaded for this class (not the actual implementation, but an overly simplified version):

```
bool operator==(const SomeClass &A, const SomeClass &B){
    if (A[0] == B[0])
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

This would throw a compiler error, since the overloaded `[]` operator requires the instance to be non-`const`. However, if I change the definition of the `[]` operator to allow for `const` instances, I can no longer do assignment:

```
// ASSUMING: const float& operator[](const unsigned i) const;

SomeClass a;
a[0] = 0; // error, because the return value of [] is a reference to const!
```

I really don't want to drop the `const` in the parameters of the `==` operator, since the operands don't change within the function. What is the right way to deal with this issue?

Comment: I'm confused, could you make a [mre]? Your `operator==` needs to be a friend the way you've declared it. Also, what does `operator==` have to do with being able to assign to a reference returned by `operator[]`?

Comment: `if (cond) return true; else return false;` ➡︎ `return cond;`

Comment: @KonradRudolph that one drives me up a wall too.  If I had a dollar for every time I've seen it...

Comment: @cigien: Sorry, yes it's a friend. Inside `operator==`, when I do `A[0]`, it gives an error saying there's no operator matching the operand - this is because the `[]` declared as above expects a nonconst instance of `SomeClass`. Hope things are clearer now. I'll try to make a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: OT: Using `const` for a pass-by-value parameter does not make much sense in a function declaration (it may have in its definition though).

Comment: @TrainHeartnet As it's a `friend` function you can access private and protected functions and members of the class from it. Maybe its more applicable not to use the exposed function but rather the "visible internals" for the comparison.

Comment: Example: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/MGro9E

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Overload `operator []` to provide both:

```
float& operator [](unsigned int i);
float operator [](unsigned int i) const;
```

For a generic `T` that’s not cheap to copy, use a `T const&` return value. The general pattern for implementing read/write `operator []` is

```
T& operator [](index_type i);
T const& operator [](index_type i) const;
```

Comment: This is perfect for a `float` return value, but if you're returning a class that's expensive to copy you can make the return type `const MyClass&` instead.